# How to prove things about primitive strings?

Tags: idris

On Idris, it is not possible to perform pattern matching against primitive strings. As such, it is not obvious how to prove things about them. For example, this function may return a proof that the first character of a list of chars is 'a':

```
f : (l : List Char) -> Maybe (head' l = Just 'a')
f ('a' :: []) = Just Refl
f xs          = Nothing
```

Which is pretty simple and passes the type checker. If we try to implement the same thing for native strings, though, we'll write something like this:

```
g : (s : String) -> Maybe (prim__strHead s = 'a')
g s = if prim__strHead s == 'a'
  then Just Refl 
  else Nothing
```

Which fails to typecheck because the compiler obviously can't conclude `prim__strHead s == 'a'` just from the fact it passed the `prim__strHead s == 'a'` test.

What is, thus, the proper way to prove things about primitive strings?

Comment: Instead of using `Maybe` for the proof, use `Dec`:

     f : (l : List Char) -> Dec (head' l = Just 'a')
     f ('a' :: xs) = Yes Refl
     f [] = No absurd

Comment: @asandroq any link explaining what is `Dec` and when/why should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested on IRC, you could use `Data.String.Views.strList` to pattern match on strings:

```
import Data.String.Views

g : (s : String) -> ...
g s with (strList s) 
 g ""            | SNil = ?no
 g (strCons x _) | SCons x _ with (decEq x 'a') 
   g (strCons 'a' _) | SCons 'a' _ | Yes Refl = ?yes
   g (strCons  x  _) | SCons  x  _ | No contra = ?no2
```